# c++ switch enum error

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I'm making a simple switch function using enums, however i'm getting the error 'ACT' undefined identifier. in AS.cpp. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here...

If you could please help explain why I am getting this error that'd be great. THankyou

```
//AS.h

#ifndef AS_H
#define AS_H

class AS {
private:
    enum class state_region;

public:

    int determine_FDI(state_region selected_state_region);
};

#endif



/////////AS.cpp
        #include "AS.h"

enum class state_region {ACT};

int AS::determine_FDI(state_region selected_state_region) {
    int FDI;

    switch (selected_state_region) {
    case ACT:
        FDI = 100;
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to use `state_region::ACT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **enum class state_region** inside **class AS** is not defined. See comments:

```
/////////AS.cpp
#include "AS.h"

// This defines ::state_region in the global scope
//enum class state_region {ACT};

// This is the definition of AS::state_region
enum class AS::state_region {ACT};
```

Second, the enumerators of **enum class** are not available in the global scope. You need to use **state_region::**ACT to access it:

```
int AS::determine_FDI(state_region selected_state_region) {
    int FDI;

    switch (selected_state_region) {
    case state_region::ACT:           // <-- state_region:: required
        FDI = 100;
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"enum class" introduced in C++11 is also called "scoped enumeration".

This clearly highlights the difference with "enum", enum values are now living in a dedicated scope.

You need to add the scope to your "case" like this:

```
case state_region::ACT:
```

instead of

```
case ACT:
```

This last line is looking for ACT identifier in your current scope but it fails to find it, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked correctly:

```
/////////AS.cpp
#include "AS.h"

enum class AS::state_region {ACT};

int AS::determine_FDI(state_region selected_state_region) {
    int FDI;

    switch (selected_state_region) {
        case state_region::ACT:
            FDI = 100;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `enum class` as opposed to traditional `enums`, the enum values are scoped inside of it, which means you have to use them like this: `state_region::ACT`. The advantage of having to do this is that now multiple enums can use the same value names.

Also, the way you define `state_region` in cpp file makes it a new enum in global scope. To properly define the one that you declared inside of the class, use `enum class AS::state_region {ACT};` (the same way you define methods and static fields).